# Spawn point not working on unity

Tags: unity

I have two `GameObjects` set down. One is named `Spawn Point`, and it is set at the beginning of my level, and `Death Point`, set down at about 0,-40,0. My code tries to see if the character is below the `Death Point` area and moves the player to the spawn point. I feel that the answer is so simple, that I could look it up, but I looked it up, and I didn't see it.

```cs
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class death : MonoBehaviour
{
    public GameObject spawnPoint;
    public GameObject deathPoint;
    // Start is called before the first frame update

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
       Vector3 playerPos = transform.position;
        if(playerPos.y < deathPoint.transform.position.y) {
            transform.position = spawnPoint.transform.position;
        }
    }
}
```

A big thank you in adavance.

Comment: Is there a reason why you do not want to have just a collider on your death area and on trigger/ hit you consider your player dead and move him?

Comment: @Zibelas I want it to be for my entire huge level. I probably could do that, but that's plan B if this doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

Well, there is nothing wrong with your code. So, if it does not work, there must be some other reason. When this happens I would add some Debug.Log() calls and check what is going on. In a case like this, I would add one line at the beginning of the Update().

```
void Update()
{
    Debug.Log("p: " + transform.position.ToString() 
        + ", d: " + deathPoint.transform.position.ToString());
```

If you don't get any messages in the console the object is probably disabled. Make sure there is a checkbox in front of the script title in the Editor.

[image]

I would also add a second line inside the if-statement to check if it ever evaluates to true.

```
    if (playerPos.y < deathPoint.transform.position.y)
    {
        Debug.Log("Is below!");
```

If this never evaluates to true:

1. The fields have other game objects assigned to them than expected.
2. Some other script is interfering. If you can - disable other scripts that might alter the position of the character.
3. If you are using physics (rigid bodies and colliders), make sure there isn't a collider on the deathPoint and your player is simply stopped by it before your script evaluates the position.

(Sorry if parts of my answer are too simple for you, then ignore those.)